# JSP contains invalid expressions: <c:set var="paramName" value="${ request.getParameter( 'name' ) }" />

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a very simple line in my JSP.

```
<c:set var="paramName" value="${ request.getParameter( 'name' ) }" />
```

I get the following error:

```
"${ request.getParameter('name') }" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error parsing '${ request.getParameter('name') }': syntax error at position 23, encountered '(', expected '}'
```

I can't see anything wrong with my code.  What's going on?

Comment: You could try using ${param.name}

Comment: @rickz - well, you were correct and it now works!  While my original code did work in production, it did output the errors.  Anyone with an explanation as to why?

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using? You should read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info     request is a JSP implicit variable. It is not a EL implicit variable. In other words, you could use <%=request.getParameter( 'name' ) %> But, the use of JSP expressions are frowned on here.